# How does Iron Man protect himself against magnets?

Tags: marvel, iron-man

I know that Iron Man has protection against EMPs, but does he have any protection against magnets?

Have his enemies tried to manipulate him with magnets and succeeded or failed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) In "Iron Man: Armored Adventures" animated series ("The X-Factor" episode, aired March 21 2012), they [pit Magneto against Iron Man](http://marvel.com/news/story/18347/magneto_attacks_iron_man_armored_adventures)

> (in the conclusion) Using a special armor, Iron Man fights Magneto with War Machine's help. Both Iron Man and War Machine had a hard time fighting Magneto and his magnetic powers. Using his special force field, Iron Man blocks Magneto's magnetic attacks

[image]

---

2) There is likely some protection, since for the up-coming [AvX comics](http://www.badhaven.com/comics/comic-news/avx-magneto-vs-iron-man-dude-in-armour-vs-master-of-magnetism-bad-odds-for-tony/), they are planning a match against Magneto, which - absent some magnetism protection - would be utterly ridiculous:

[image]

---

As a side note, Iron Man Costume (at least MK 1) could **use** magnetism. From [Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/Iron_Man_Armor_MK_I):

> Magnetism: Iron Man’s armor was equipped with an array of miniature electromagnetic generators that allowed him to manipulate magnetic fields for a variety of effects:
>   - Jamming - Iron Man could generate electromagnetic interference which could be used to jam transmissions or disrupt the function of nearby electrical equipment. (First demonstrated in Tales of Suspense #39)
>   - Reverse Magnetism - Iron Man could redirect the path of ferrous projectiles in flight. (First demonstrated in Tales of Suspense #39)

Answer (score 6):

In AvX: VS #1, they pit Iron Man against Magneto. It was revealed within the first few pages that Iron Man's armor (in current comic-book lore) is made of carbon nanotubes, not iron:

[image: A page from AvX: VS #1 showing Iron Man describing his carbon nanotube armor]

Answer (score 5):

Speaking purely from the movie, the suit was a Gold/Titanium alloy. Neither of which is is magnetic.

That being said, there has to me large numbers of wires/etc that are likely to be magnetic and would have to be shielded.

Comment: Well, if we want to be purely accurate all matter is magnetic, given a strong enough magnetic field (this is how nMRI/MRI machines work). However, yes the amount of energy needed to align the spin of the atoms in Gold and Titanium is quite high.

Comment: I wonder how much energy you'd need to make the human skeleton magnetic.